# Cannot use useContext hook in Custom Drawer Content Functional Component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to implement User Login with an AuthContext and useContext hook. And if the user is logged in I wan to show user's name in Drawer. But when I try to access the useContext in CustomDrawerContent functional component the following errors occur.

the error : [image]

//App.JsCodes

```
export default function App() {
 
  const [user,setUser] = useState();
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{user,setUser}}>
    <NavigationContainer>
      
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="MenuTab" drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent}>
      
        
        <Drawer.Screen name="MenuTab" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
        
      </Drawer.Navigator>
      
    </NavigationContainer>
    
    </AuthContext.Provider>
```

//CustomDrawerContend.js

```
function CustomDrawerContent({navigation}) {

      const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
      useEffect(() => {
            console.log('the CustomDrawerContent '+user);
      },[]);
      
      
    
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, paddingBottom:-30}}>
           

           <TouchableOpacity style={{}} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("MenuTab")}>
                <View style={{justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center", padding:25, backgroundColor:"#bbe3fc", paddingTop:80}}>
                  <Image style={{height:65, width:65}} source={require('../../assets/profileLogo.png')} />
                  <Text>{user ? user.email : 'Sasindu'}</Text>
```

//SignInCodeBlock

```
const data = await response.json();
                if (data.code=== 200) {
                    authContext.setUser(data.data);
                    console.log('Sign in screen user '+JSON.stringify(authContext.user));
                    setLoggedUser(data.data);
                    navigation.navigate('DrawerNav');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent} is another prop that's being passed into Drawer.Navigator. Hence it is unauthorized to use the useContext inside that kind of props. Since the requirement is to show the Logged user name, I used another component just to return the logged user name and I was able to use the useContext inside that Functional component and it worked well. And added that new component into where I wanted to show the user name in CustomDrawerContent functional component. Remember the hooks can only be called inside unique functional components. [check this as well](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

```
function ShowLoggedUsername(props) {
const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);

return (
    <View>
        <Text>{user ? user.email : 'Username' }</Text>
    </View>
);
```

}

export default ShowLoggedUsername;

the CustomDrawerContent FC

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{}} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("MenuTab")}>
            <View style={{justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center", padding:25, backgroundColor:"#bbe3fc", paddingTop:80}}>
              <Image style={{height:65, width:65}} source={require('../../assets/profileLogo.png')} />
              <ShowLoggedUsername />
              <Button title="Log-Out" />
              
            </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```